# Trying to access array offset on value of type bool PHP

Tags: php, pdo

When I want to register a new user I have error

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in P:\xampp\htdocs\BTP\v4\register.php on line 37

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in P:\xampp\htdocs\BTP\v4\register.php on line 39

Still, it all works, and user create
but I want to fix it and I don't know what's wrong

```
<?php
require_once 'include/database.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn_register'])){

    $fname = strip_tags($_REQUEST['fname']);
    $lname = strip_tags($_REQUEST['lname']);
    $email = strip_tags($_REQUEST['email']);
    $phone = strip_tags($_REQUEST['phone']);
    $password = strip_tags($_REQUEST['password']);
    $rpassword = strip_tags($_REQUEST['passwordrepet']);

    if(empty($fname)){
        $errorMsg[] = "Proszę podać imię";
    }else if(empty($lname)){
        $errorMsg[] = "Proszę podać nazwisko";
    }else if(empty($email)){
        $errorMsg[] = "Proszę podać adres e-mail";
    }else if(empty($password)){
        $errorMsg[] = "Proszę podać hasło";
    }else if(empty($rpassword)){
        $errorMsg[] = "Należy ponownie podać hasło";
    }else if(strlen($password) < 6){
        $errorMsg[] = "Hasło musi zawierać conajmniej 6 znaków";
    }else if($password != $rpassword){
        $errorMsg[] = "Hasła nie są takie same";
    }else{

        try{
            $select_stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT email, phone FROM user WHERE email=:email OR phone=:phone");
            $select_stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $select_stmt->bindValue(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $select_stmt->execute();

            $row = $select_stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
            if($row['email'] == $email){
                $errorMsg[] = "Adres e-mail jest już zajęty";
            }else if($row['phone'] == $phone){
                $errorMsg[] = "Numer telefonu został juz podany do innego konta";
            }else if(!isset($errorMsg)){

                $new_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

                $insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user (fname, lname, email, phone, password) VALUES (:fname, :lname, :email, :phone, :password)");

                if($insert_stmt->execute(array( ':fname' =>$fname,
                                                ':lname' =>$lname,
                                                ':email' =>$email,
                                                ':phone' =>$phone,
                                                ':password' => $new_password))){

                    $registerMsg = "Udało sie zarejestrować";
                }

            }

        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Best Trip Partner Register</title>

    <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
    <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body class="bg-gradient-primary">

    <div class="container">

        <div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
            <div class="card-body p-0">
                <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-7">
                        <div class="p-5">
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Utwórz konto</h1>
                            </div>
                            <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" class="user">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleFirstName" placeholder="Imię">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="text" name="lname" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleLastName" placeholder="Nazwisko">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputEmail" placeholder="Adres e-mail">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="phone" name="phone" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPhone" placeholder="Numer telefonu">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                                        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" placeholder="Hasło">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <input type="password" name="passwordrepet" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleRepeatPassword" placeholder="Powtórz hasło">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <?php
                                print_r($row);
                                    if(isset($errorMsg)){
                                        foreach($errorMsg as $error){
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                                <strong><?php echo $error; ?></strong>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if(isset($registerMsg)){
                                        ?>
                                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                                <strong><?php echo $registerMsg; ?></strong>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php
                                    }
                                ?>
                                <button type="submit" name="btn_register" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Zarejestruj się</button>

                            </form>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="forgot-password.php">Zapomniałeś hasła?</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <a class="small" href="login.php">Masz już konto? Zaloguj się!</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If fetch fails, it'll return false.

Comment: But when i do echo $row['email'] I see email and it's correct

Comment: You can do print_r($row) to verify what's being returned.

Comment: Result Array ( [email] => john@mail.com [phone] => 123456123 )

Comment: Okay, after submitting the form, it doesn't show what it contains, but I don't know why. Now i edit and show all code meaby someone see waht is wrong. I don't have the strength anymore

Comment: You should add a condition to check if row is false. Because if no matching records are found I do believe false is still returned for an empty result.

Comment: If no record with the email or phone number exists in the database - then your query will not return _any_ rows, so what exactly did you expect `fetch` to return in that case then? You should check how many rows your query returned first.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please use `array_key_exists()` function to check if the key email and phone exist in your variable.
Something like...

```
if (array_key_exists("email", $row)) {
   if ($row['email'] == $email) {
      $errorMsg[] = "Adres e-mail jest już zajęty";
 }
}
```

Comment: Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in P:\xampp\htdocs\BTP\v4\register.php on line 36   if(array_key_exists($row["email"], $row['phone'])){

Comment: it makes no sense to check if the key email and phone exist in your variable. they always exist, given query returned any rows